# Multilingual Content in CKAN

Tags: ckan

Is it possible to enable multilingual content in CKAN? I am aware that the CKAN interface is multilingual. But we'd like the site to show content (dataset name/description, resource name etc) in language which matches the interface language selected by visitors to the site.

For example, the dataset publisher create a dataset with 3 name fields in English, Spanish and Chinese. When a visitor views the site in Chinese, he only sees the Chinese dataset name.

I've tried adding custom fields to the package and hacking the templates. It is not very elegant. And it only work for the dataset level, not at the resource level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CKAN's multilingual extension: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/multilingual.html. Also, [data.gc.ca](http://data.gc.ca/eng) went with [their own multilingual solution](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/Multilingual-Datasets,-the-Government-of-Canada-approach).